# Search through list of registered domain names (.com)

Tags: domain, domain-name

I need to "search" for domain names that might be infringing on my companies' trademarks. Is there any site/services which allow "searching" through the registered lists of domain names (right now for .com only) and shows me what have been registered already.

I'm not looking for a service which takes keywords and suggests new names for me.

Comment: I think you can only use a normal search like google. There is no easy way to query the dns system with wildcards. DNS is a very large database that is widely spread over multiple servers.

Comment: i dont see a problem with that... i dont need up-to-the-minute information... i've heard of things called the zones file being present which contain this informaiton, but cant locate a way to "search" within them...

Comment: DNS and google won;t really help you as there maybe domains that are registered but not delegated. DNS won;t help you find registered but undelegated domains.
Google might somehow find them but there are no guarantees.

Comment: The only domain names which could be infringing on your company's trademarks are those using said trademarks as their name. It follows therefore that you merely need to do a whois on each trademark. However, this has absolutely nothing to do with system administration.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the searching yourself for this information, you need to get the zones from the TLDs that you are interested in looking for.  For example, [Verisign has some documents to fill out to apply to get copies of the zones they manage](http://www.verisign.com/domain-name-services/domain-information-center/tld-zone-access/index.html).  You will need to do this for each of the zones you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the sort of service [MarkMonitor](http://www.markmonitor.com/) is offering.

Comment: Yes, that's what i need to do, but not engage them on a permanent basis...

Answer (score 1):

I'll just throw this out there as well. Our company recently went on a hunt for infringing or cybersquatting domains for our brand. After several attempts to do this ourselves, we realized that hiring a 3rd party to do this for us proved to be way more cost effective. A company that we've had great success with is CitizenHawk:

http://www.citizenhawk.com/

They've been able to recover over 300+ infringing domains. It was a shock to see how many people cybersquatted misspelled versions of our domains. If you're serious about hunting down these cybersquatters, I suggest enlisting their help.

Answer (score 0):

Any proper WHOIS service like http://whois.domaintools.com/ can do this.

Comment: This returns one domain only... I'm not sure if any provider or website allows you to do a meta search in dns and return all results! DNS is wide spread and very large system.

Answer (score 0):

Google your companies name. Considering those guys index a good chunk of the web you can, using your name as a keyword in the search would give you potential possibilities.

The question basically boils down to this. names are delegated. At the top is root, then .com. So you'd have to go to all the ones you cared about like the .com provider(verisign) .net(verisign again) and get access to their list of domains from the main databases(which must be huge and spread across multiple servers I imagine) and do a massive text based search.

1) Good luck with that. I doubt they'd help you even if you paid them loads of money
2) That search is going to be awhile and only grab certain aspects. so if your trademark is HAPPYFUNDAYOMG then searching for that wont show mispellings like HAPYFUNDAYOMG.

That's why I say just use Google.

Comment: How can I use google to search"for" certain words in domain names only?

Comment: Try using the inurl search operator.  http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html#inurl

Comment: wowie zored! that's fantastic - why dont you answer separately and i'll click that answer. It isnt exactly what i'm looking for, but its darn close!!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the domain names you are interested in whois is the correct answer as that will identify domains that are registered, even if they are not delegated (i.e. even if DNS is not set up for them).

You can script it pretty easily, albeit crudely with bash and I would be very surprised if there were not libraries for interrogating whois in perl, python etc if you wanted to do less crude searching/reporting.
If you don't have a list of specifc domains you are interested in, then I think you are out of luck.

Of course you can somehow generate a list of domains to search based on keywords/your trademarks, then query whois.

Comment: I'd go for this one, although that means a lot of cases to check (including testing tons of TLDs probably). Edit: actually, I found that Gandi has an API for this, see my answer.

Comment: How would this work for me? I care about what others have registered, not what possibly could be registered which would be close to infinite!

Answer (score 0):

[Gandi](http://gandi.net) has an API to check these kinds of things: http://wiki.gandi.net/en/api-xml

You can make a script using this API to check the names you want.

The full documentation for the XMLRPC service can be found on http://wiki.gandi.net/fr/api-xml/docs/domain/domain.
An example can be found on http://www.gandi-test.fr/search.php.

Comment: Am i missing something  - this doesnt seem to allow searches THRU  existing domains...